# using Numpy for Kmean Clustering

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I'm new in machine learning and want to build a Kmean algorithm with k = 2 and I'm struggling by calculate the new centroids. here is my code for kmeans:

```
def euclidean_distance(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
   # x shape: (N1, D)
   # y shape: (N2, D)
   # output shape: (N1, N2)
    dist = []
    for i in x:
       for j in y:
        new_list = np.sqrt(sum((i - j) ** 2))
        dist.append(new_list)
    distance = np.reshape(dist, (len(x), len(y)))
    return distance

def kmeans(x, centroids, iterations=30):
    assignment = None
    for i in iterations:
        dist = euclidean_distance(x, centroids)
        assignment = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)

    for c in range(len(y)):
        centroids[c] = np.mean(x[assignment == c], 0) #error here
    
        return centroids, assignment
```

I have input `x = [[1., 0.], [0., 1.], [0.5, 0.5]]` and `y = [[1., 0.], [0., 1.]]` and
`distance` is an array and look like that:

```
[[0.         1.41421356]
[1.41421356 0.         ]
[0.70710678 0.70710678]]
```

and when I run `kmeans(x,y)` then it returns error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_40086/2170434798.py in 
> 5
> 6 for c in range(len(y)):

> ----> 7     centroids[c] = (x[classes == c], 0)
> 8     print(centroids)
>
> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

Does anyone know how to fix it or improve my code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: please post the full traceback, and specify the line where the error occured

Comment: the line `centroids[c] = np.mean(x[assignment == c], 0)` occurred  error (like I was comment in code)

Comment: I agree with Arav R's answer below. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Changing inputs to NumPy arrays should get rid of errors:

```py
x = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.], [0.5, 0.5]])
y = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]])
```

Also seems like you must change `for i in iterations` to `for i in range(iterations)` in `kmeans` function.

Comment: oh thank you. it's another bug. But the main error I already fixed it.